# search a content in my website and result should be provide as links in a new page

Tags: php, api

```
<form id="searchForm" method="get" action="search.php">
<input type="text" name="keyword" class="text1" value="" placeholder="SEARCH"  style="text-align:center;"/>
<input type="hidden" name="site" class="text1" value="www.mysite.com"/>
<input type="submit" class="text2" name="search" value="Search" />
```

search.php

```
<?php
$query = $_POST['keyword'];
$site = $_POST['site'];
$url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&"
    . "q={$query}+Site:{$site}&userip=USERS-IP-ADDRESS";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'my site url');
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json = json_decode($body);
?>
```

I would like to print search result as links that belongs to my site only eg (google search result)

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach to loop the data and add it on href tag and add [target="_blank"](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) to open the link on new tab.

```
<?php 
foreach ($json as $key => $value) { ?>
<a href="<?php echo $value ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $value; ?></a>
<?php  }  ?>
```